# MongoDb aggregation query: for every array count the number of properties of nested object

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have documents with the following structure:

```
"_id" : "AQ106_2020-09-12T09",
"date" : "2020-09-12T09:00:00.000Z",
"station" : {
    "name" : "AQ106",
    "loc" : {
        "type" : "Point",
        "coordinates" : [
            14.339263,
            40.814224
        ]
    },
    "properties" : {
        
    }
},
"samples" : [
    {
        "t" : ISODate("2020-09-12T11:02:00.000+02:00"),
        "data" : {
            "pm1_mg_m3" : 2.7,
            "pm2_5_mg_m3" : 4.6,
            "pm10_mg_m3" : 12,
            "P0" : 152,
            "P1" : 16,
            "P2" : 4.7,
            "P3" : 0.8,
            "P4" : 0.86,
            "P5" : 0.6,
            "P6" : 0.28,
            "P7" : 0.152,
            "P8" : 0.094,
            "P9" : 0.092,
            "P10" : 0.019,
            "P11" : 0,
            "P12" : 0,
            "P13" : 0.0188,
            "P14" : 0,
            "P15" : 0,
            "P16" : 0,
            "P17" : 0,
            "P18" : 0,
            "P19" : 0,
            "P20" : 0,
            "P21" : 0,

                "P22" : 0,
                "P23" : 0,
                "temp_celsius" : 32.59,
                "humRelPercent" : 34,
                "press_mBar" : 1010.79,
                "CO2mA" : 4,
                "NO2_WE_mV" : 226.419,
                "NO2_AE_mV" : 229.553,
                "OX_WE_mV" : 252.287,
                "OX_AE_mV" : 220.419,
                "CO_WE_mV" : 509.077,
                "AE_WE_mV" : 348.51,
                "batt_V" : 13.5,
                "source_V" : 17.6
            }
        },
        .... additional arrays
}
```

Each document in the collection has a `samples` field that is an array of objects, each having a `t` field of type ISODate and a `data` field of type object containing sensors readings.
I would like to count the number of properties into object `samples.data` for each element in  `samples` and filter documents having this count == N.
How can do that?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a small change that is to use `filter` instead of `map`

```
{
    $project: {
      station: "$station.name",
      "n": {
        $filter: {
          input: "$samples.data",
          cond: {
            $eq: [
              {
                $size: {
                  "$objectToArray": "$$this"
                }
              },
              39
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Working [Mongo playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/rnLBP1cdFwg)

Comment: Thanks, but it does not work as expected. If you only add another doc with less then 39 properties into `samples.data` it returns both the docs. See [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/QpCmTf4Q5mc)

Comment: @EanX https://mongoplayground.net/p/MJJdTm1wHxb does this help you?

Answer (score 0):

I partially figured it out using the aggregation framework as:

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$project: {
  station:'$station.name',
  n:{$map:
  {
    input:"$samples.data",
    as:"vals",
    in:  {
        $size: {
          "$objectToArray": "$$vals"
        }
      }

      }}
}}])
```

But how to filter documents?